# TensorFlow, tf.one_hot why the shape of output is defined by the value of axis?

Tags: tensorflow

I read the [docs of tf.one_hot](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/one_hot) and found that

> ... . The new axis is created at dimension axis (default: the new axis is appended at the end).

What is `The new axis`?

> If indices is a vector of length features, the output shape will be:
>
> > features x depth if axis == -1
> >
> > depth x features if axis == 0
>
> If indices is a matrix (batch) with shape [batch, features], the output shape will be:
>
> > batch x features x depth if axis == -1
> >
> > batch x depth x features if axis == 1
> >
> > depth x batch x features if axis == 0

Why the shape of output is defined by axis?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`tf.one_hot()` transforms a list of indices (e.g. `[0, 2, 1]`) and transforms it into a list of one-hot vectors of length `depth`.

For instance, if `depth = 3`,

- index 0 in the input will be replaced by [1, 0, 0]
- index 1 in the input will be replaced by [0, 1, 0]
- index 2 in the input will be replaced by [0, 0, 1]

So `[0, 2, 1]` would be encoded as `[[1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0]]`

As you can see, the output has one more dimension than the input (since each index is replaced by a vector).

By default (**and what you usually need**), the new dimension is created as the last one, so if your input is of shape `(d1, d2, .., dn)`, your output will be of shape `(d1, d2, .., dn, depth)`. But if you change the input parameter *axis*, you may choose to put the new dimension elsewhere, for instance if `axis=0` your output will be of shape `(depth, d1, d2, .., dn)`.

Changing the order of the dimensions is basically the n-dimensional version of transposing: you have the same data, but switch the order of the indices to access them (equivalent to switching the columns and the rows in a 2D matrix).

Comment: Since `If the input indices is rank N, the output will have rank N+1.`, the value of axis is the index of depth of  output